# Filtering SPAM on AskUbuntu

Tags: feature-request, spam-handling, spam

Why are `beauty products` spam being constantly posted on AskUbuntu? Its very irritating. I know that this cannot be filtered by bots but aren't there a faster way to delete these spams? There had always been a spam or two every 15 mins or so and then, it takes another `10-15 mins` or so before its removed from the site.

Here's a screenshot to that:

[image: 1]

Comment: It's a holiday, there aren't that many people around. Usually it is removed a lot faster. It's worth pointing out too that 6 spam flags will automatically remove a post and that once it receives 4 downvotes it is no longer shown on the front page (casting a spam flag auto downvotes it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's just one piece of spam, with very few few people on-line it can takes about 15 minutes before it's finally taken down, *but on busy days, it takes about a minute* and when we man the spam stations during a big spam wave, **it takes about 2 seconds to get flagged into oblivion!**

## ;-)

#### So keep on flagging!  Eventually the spammers will give up!

<sub>No, they won't: there are always new spammers around that don't know that they shouldn't even try to spam here...</sub>

Comment: Just admit, it was your spam post, wasn't it? :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm: yes, I'm a fireman that likes to set fire to houses to be able to extinguish them!  **:D**